# How to add a Group Owner in Azure AD for the Group synced from on-premises active directory

Tags: azure-active-directory

I need to add group owners to the groups which are synced from on-prem Active directory. The functionality i am trying to use require that value.

I tried adding in AD (managed by) but it does not sync to Azure and also tried using add-azureadgroupowner PS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Synchronized object are only editable in your on-premises directory. Not in cloud. In that manner, setting group owner of a synchronized group does not bring any value.

The idea of group owner is to enable self-service functionalities in Azure AD. The group owner can, for example manage group memberships for the group one owns. But a synchronized group is locked for editing in cloud. Meaning that group owner will have no special privileges.

A potential solution to your task would be to configure [Directory Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-directory-extensions) and synchronize additional group extension properties which you can later read in the cloud.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In the case of access reviews, in which it has an option to make group owner as access reviewer, it adds value to populate group owner attribute for the on-premises group however it seems like we cannot do that.