# Issue with using of PowerShell module for Azure AD to manage groups

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

fellow engineers!

There is a need to transfer group owner from attribute "managedBy" (`CN=%username%;` part) of on-prem AD to Azure AD's "Owner" field of the same group (groups are synchronized, so it has same naming both in on-prem and Azure AD).

Issue is, that the process need to be automated, but there is not much options:

1. Module for AAD group management for PowerShell (but it doesn't work PowerShell ver7, because of .Net's core issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/49896): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-settings-v2-cmdlets
2. Answer from another question on StackOverflow, but it doesn't seem to be my thing (because the need to deal with Extensions): [How to add a Group Owner in Azure AD for the Group synced from on-premises active directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57981779/how-to-add-a-group-owner-in-azure-ad-for-the-group-synced-from-on-premises-activ)
3. Some kind of work-around with Graph API, but it isn't my choice too, since process need to be automated: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4a293240-5ffc-45be-bd73-43f8868e5fab/graph-api-getting-quotmanaged-byquot-attribute-for-a-group-synced-with-azure-ad-connect?forum=WindowsAzureAD

So, maybe somebody stuck with same need or maybe could suggest a workaround with the PowerShell module, since there is not much of pleasure to go through more than 100 groups adding owners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   Since, all the on-premises Active Directory groups are synced to Azure AD and all the groups have the same naming in Azure AD as that of on-premises active directory, then you can change the group owners of all the groups that are synced from on-premises AD to AAD by executing the below commands: -

```
 ‘ Get-AzureADGroup | Where {$_.DirSyncEnabled -eq $true} | Select -Property 
  DisplayName,DirSyncEnabled,LastDirSyncTime | export-csv ‘C:\syncgroup.csv’ | 
  ft -auto ’ --> This will give a list of all the groups with their object IDs 
  that are synced to Azure AD from Active Directory. Export them to a csv file 
  through the export-csv command.
```

•   Once exported, then arrange the csv file by inserting the reference id of the service principal that is assigned the owner of the group synced. The run the below script for assigning the group owner membership to the reference id to all the groups present in the csv file.

```
  $Groups = Import-Csv "C:\syncgroup.csv"
  foreach ($Group in $Groups)
  {
     if (Get-AzureADGroup | Where {$_.DisplayName -eq $Group.DisplayName})
      {
        Write-Host "Getting ObjectID for: "$Group.DisplayName
        $ObjectID = (Get-AzureADGroup | Where {$_.ObjectID -eq 
        $Group.ObjectID}).ObjectID
        $ReferenceID = (Get-AzureADGroup | Where {$_.ReferenceID -eq 
        $Group.ReferenceID}).ReferenceID
        $ObjectID
        $ReferenceID
        #Add-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $ObjectID -RefObjectId $ReferenceID
      }
  }
```

Please refer the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadgroupowner?view=azureadps-2.0

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c667b0ce-2db6-466c-8190-fa501c554b3f/need-help-bulk-removing-groups-in-azure-ad?forum=WindowsAzureAD